# Pass data to Angular google chart

Tags: angular, google-visualization

I am using Google Charts for Angular 7. I would like to pass `reportData` which is generated dynamically into the drawChart function.

```
   var reportData = {"High":100, "Medium" : 200, "Low" : 300}

    generateChart() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          GoogleCharts.load(drawChart);
        }, 500);
    }

    function drawChart(reportData) {

          let data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Category', 'Value'],
            ['High', reportData.High],
            ['Medium', reportData.Medium],
            ['Low', reportData.Low]
          ]);

          let options = {
            chartArea: { left: 30, top: 30, width: '70%', height: '70%' },
            enableInteractivity: true,
            legend: { position: 'bottom' },
            colors: ['#ccc', '#ddd', '#eee']
          };

          let chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
```

Comment: is `reportData` available when `drawChart` is called? why not pass it as an argument?

Comment: yes.. It is available. reportData is generated when a subscribe method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass `reportData` as an argument to `drawChart`...

```
    setTimeout(() => {
      GoogleCharts.load(() => {
        drawChart(reportData);
      });
    }, 500);

function drawChart(reportData) {

      let data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(reportData);
```